# Netbook : extreme power-saving

Tags: power-management

I am the happy owner of an `Asus EeePC 1005PX` with very low-end hardware and a pretty big battery. I am looking for the most **power-saving** distribution of Linux, and/or kernel attached, because I can't go over 4h20 of battery-life, and I used to do more before (like 6 to 7 hours. "Before" was always better, you know it).

#### My specs

- 10' - 1024x600 LED screen (maybe it's LCD, 'because I had to change it, and ordered one from Czechia or something like that on Ebay)
- CPU Intel Atom N450
- Integrated graphics
- 2Gb DDR2 SDRAM (I can go back to 1Gb if it means more powersave)
- HDD 250Gb SATA 5400rpm
- Integrated : 2x USB2.0 | 1x SDcard | 1x VGA | 1x Webcam + Microphone

#### My typical use

Only on battery :

- Class notes (nano would clearly be enough... although italics and bold are useful)

Always :

- Web search (+ Flash for youtube/streaming video)

Only on charge :

- Watching movies (with headphones)
- Listening to music (with headphones)

#### My choices

I was thinking... maybe I could use two distributions :

- one for travelling and class, which would be veeeery lightweight and energy-saving, something like minimal arch installation with xfce and only mousepad/midori installed.
- another one "regular" for movies and stuff, like Ubuntu with LibreOffice, Firefox, Flashplugin, blablabla.

#### My questions

1. Would the power-consuming *really* differ from one configuration to another ?
2. What would be, *factually*, the most power-efficient `kernel`, `desktop environment` and `web-browser` I should use ?
3. Among these packages, programs, ideas, which are good (for power-save, of course) :

   `pm-powersave`, *"powertop recommended settings"*, *"2D environment"*, *"32 bit architecture instead of 64 bit"*, `linrunner/tlp`, `laptop-mode-tools`, *"High contrast mode"*, *"downclock hardware"*, *"`CONFIG_MATOM` used in kernel)"*
4. *Bonus question* : Can I achieve "Deep Power Down Technology (C6)" with my Netbook and/or tweak voltage, if my BIOS doesn't let me touch anything except global stuffs ?

Comment: Try [CPU Power Manager](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/945/cpu-power-manager/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Even if you had libreoffice, Firefox, etc installed, but not running, that would noy make much too difference to battery life.

**2)** With the kernels, power usage it probably based more on how you use them.

LXDE or Xfce seem the most efficient desktop enivroments to use - if you are using `nano`, why don't just not login to the graphical desktop environments, and just use the tty's (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>) - works for me :-)

Midori or Seamonkey *(like Firefox)* are fairly efficient.

**3)** & **4)** dunno

Basically, use the minimum amount of things as possible, and stop any power hungry processes - you can find them using `top`, and kill them in `top` by using <kbd>k</kbd> and typing the PID. Keeping CPU usage to a minimal, and use non Graphic intensive programs.

You may also want to remember that hardware other than RAM uses power - namely the Wifi and screen backlight. You can usually activate and deactivate these using keyboard shortucts, like <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

---

Just thought I would add this - I find [`indicator-cpufreq`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/indicator-cpufreq/) useful on my work laptop, as setting it to power seems to add an extra hours battery life. In 13.10, you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

Comment: I can't only use nano because I have to use a web-browser at the same time.

Comment: It is useful during lectures and things anyway.

Comment: It is useful even if the full desktop runs in tty7 ?

Comment: It can be, as it seems to pause some processes in the graphical desktop - it would probably then have similar performance as it would if it was being run in a terminal anyway.

Comment: Following Ubuntu wiki, black pixels are more power-needing to display than light ones. So I'm gessing tty is not a good idea. Maybe use a non-graphic session would, but certainly not a tty AND a session running together.